# Zend_Form_Element_File multiple file upload and mysql

Tags: zend-framework

Does anybody knows a working example to receive multiple files, store them in a folder and the names in a mysql table? Some days already with no luck at all, something always missing, and before putting those questions, well , maybe i can find the right one!

maybe?
i am learning using zend 1.11

thanks
pablo

EDIT:
i add the code for clearness:
in the form:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_File('images');
$element->setLabel('Upload bis 3 Bilder (máx. 200kb each):')
                ->setMultiFile(3)
                ->setValueDisabled(true)
                ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_File_Size('2MB'))
                ->addValidator('Count', false, array('min'=>0,'max' => 3));
```

in the controller:

```
$adapter = $form->images->getTransferAdapter();
//create directory where files would be hold
if (!file_exists(UPLOADDIR))
mkdir(UPLOADDIR, 0777, 1);

$i=0;
$images="";
//loop uploaded files

foreach ($adapter->getFileInfo() as $info)
{     
//rename file how you like and move it to given destination
$fileName = time().$i.'.'.$this->getExtension($info['name']);
$adapter->addFilter('Rename', array('target'=>UPLOADDIR.$fileName, 'overwrite'=>true));

//if something goes wrong print errors in screen
if (!$adapter->receive($info['name']))
{
die(print_r($adapter->getMessages(),1));
}else{
 if ($info['name']!==""){
 $images .= $fileName.",";
 }
}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Comments from Mona's answer: Take a look at the following examples http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/tag/uploading-multiple-files-from-a-form-with-zend-framework-zf-storing-uploaded-zf-files-with-unique-name/ and http://ahsangill.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/zend-framework-file-upload-using-zend_form_element_file/ and http://irmantasplius.blogspot.com/2009/08/zendform-multiple-file-uploads.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `setFilters()` instead of `addFilter` on the adapter, because the current code will add a new Rename filter on each iteration of the foreach loop.

Try replacing:

```
$adapter->addFilter('Rename', array('target'=>UPLOADDIR.$fileName, 'overwrite'=>true));
```

with

```
$adapter->setFilters(array(new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array('target'=>UPLOADDIR.$fileName, 'overwrite'=>true))));
```